# プログラムの簡略化

Tags: python

#### 解決したいこと

クラスタリングしたデータのクラスタIDを０から順番に引き出して重複を消して保存しているのですがクラスタの数を増やしたいとき手書きで付け加える以外のプログラムを作れませんどのようなコードを用いれば簡略化できるでしょうか

**例えばクラスタ数を100にして0から99を順番に抜き出して重複を消して保存したいとき

自分は数字を変えて長文のコードにしていたのですが100までとなると相当な労力なので簡略化したいです**。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



#csvを読み込み0
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==0]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai0.csv")



#csvを読み込み
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

#クラスタIDを抽出
X = df[df["cluster_id"]==1]
X

#重複削除
sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX
#保存
sinX.to_csv("clusternai1.csv")

#csvを読み込み2
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==2]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai2.csv")

#csvを読み込み3
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==3]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai3.csv")

#csvを読み込み4
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==4]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai4.csv")

#csvを読み込み5
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==5]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai5.csv")

#csvを読み込み6
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==6]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai6.csv")

#csvを読み込み7
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==7]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai7.csv")

#csvを読み込み8
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==8]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai8.csv")

#csvを読み込み9
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==9]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai9.csv")

#csvを読み込み10
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==10]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai10.csv")

#csvを読み込み11
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==11]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusterna11.csv")

#csvを読み込み12
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==12]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai12.csv")

#csvを読み込み13
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==13]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai13.csv")

#csvを読み込み14
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

X = df[df["cluster_id"]==14]
X

sinX = X.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
sinX

sinX.to_csv("clusternai14.csv")
```

#### 補足情報

Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: 処理内容・対称とする数値の変化・対応する名前や文字列の変化 といったものの法則性を見つけて、それを質問記事に説明できるようにしてみてください。そうすれば自分自身で解決できる可能性が高まります。

Comment: 読み込んでいるCSVは同じものですよね？ 少なくとも読み込むコード部分は一回で事足りるかと思います。

Comment: そうです一回目以外はすべて消してみます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

データがないので試してないけど

```py
df = pd.read_csv("allclsdata.csv")

for n, sdf in df.groupby('cluster_id'):
    sinX = sdf.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"], keep='last')
    display(sinX)
    sinX.to_csv(f'clusternai{n}.csv')
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。実行してみたところdisplayエラーとなってしまいますdisplayについて調べてみたもののネームエラーで何に変えればいいのかわからずにいます　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'display' is not defined

Comment: スクリプトの途中で, 内容を確認しているらしい `sinX` だけの行があるため それに相当する呼び出しをしているだけです。Jupyterでなら実行可能。必要ないなら削除可能

Comment: ありがとうございます。削除したら正常に動作しました。